# Display size of ng-repeat with filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am currently working on an analytics backend web app and am using ng-repeat to show a table for some data I am working with. Is there a way to show the number of total results found when using a filter with ng-repeat? I would like to display this beneath my table.

Comment: you could do $(table).length. This is a jquery  function which you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the filtered data in a var like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts = (products | filter:search)">
```

So inside your ng-repeat you can do something like `filteredProducts.length`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the $last variable of [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

something like this inside your ng-repeat would do the trick:

```
<div ng-if="$last"> Total results found: {{ $index + 1 }} </div>
```

*note that* you should add 1 to the $index since it starts at 0

Comment: is that not the pageindex you are displaying then?